Running a long-running process on Windows using SSH
I have a Windows machine with SSH Server installed. As part of my pipeline, I need to run Selenium server on that machine, which the rest of the pipeline will use. I've tried using Powershell's Start-Process with no success:
ssh myuser@windows_host "powershell -Command \"Start-Process 'java' '-jar selenium-server-standalone.jar' -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput 'C:\\path\\to\\logfile.log' -RedirectStandardError 'C:\\path\\to\\logfile.log'\""


Same command is good when I run it locally, but when I run it using SSH from a remote machine, it asks for a password, and then my shell returns with no output, and also the file paths used for -RedirectStandardOutput and -RedirectStandardError are both empty. No clue for what happened.
Tried to simplify things to understand what's going on with just trying to run a cmd script that just writes to a file every 5 seconds, with same results - seems that it doesn't run, and no clue to what the problem is.
